# Push notification method get call at the time of launching the app

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Whenever user clicked on push notification this method get called
func `application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]`, `fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)` but if app is getting launched and the same time push come same method gets called. How to identify if app is getting launched or user click on icon to get the app in foreground. 
So that i can ignore the push notification process.

Answer (score 0):

In `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {`

```
if (launchOptions != nil)
    {
        // Here app will open from pushnotification
        //RemoteNotification
        NSDictionary* dictionary1 = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
        //LocalNotification
        NSDictionary* dictionary2 = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
        if (dictionary1 != nil)
        {
            //RemoteNotification Payload
            //set your function to handle notification
            NSLog(@"Launched from push notification: %@", dictionary1);
        }
        if (dictionary2 != nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"Launched from dictionary2dictionary2dictionary2 notification: %@", dictionary2);
            double delayInSeconds = 7;
            dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
            dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                // [self addMessageFromRemoteNotification:dictionary2 updateUI:NO];
            });
        }

     }
     else
         {}
```

In `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {`

```
 if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive) {

        NSLog(@"Inactive - the user has tapped in the notification when app was closed or in background");
        //do some tasks

    }
    else if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground) {

        NSLog(@"application Background - notification has arrived when app was in background");
        NSString* contentAvailable = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"content-available"]];

        if([contentAvailable isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
            // do tasks
            NSLog(@"content-available is equal to 1");
        }
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"application Active - notication has arrived while app was opened");
        //Show an in-app banner
        //do tasks
    }
```